# How to display WkWebView screenshots in iOS Homescreen Widgets?

Tags: ios, swiftui, widget, ios14, widgetkit

How can I take a screenshot of a dynamic website and place the screenshot in an iOS Homescreen Widget? I'm looking to build a widget dashboard that shows an update of a website every hour or so.

For context, I know how to solve a similar problem with maps instead of webviews - you use MKMapSnapshotter in the timeline function of a widget in order to get a screenshot of a Map.

```
func getMapSnapshot(completionHandler: @escaping (Image) -> Void) {
    let coordinate = self.locationManager.location?.coordinate ?? self.defaultCoordinate
    let options = MKMapSnapshotter.Options()
    options.region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span: self.span)
    let snapshot = MKMapSnapshotter(options: options)
    snapshot.start { (snapshot, error) in
        let image = Image(uiImage: snapshot?.image ?? UIImage(named: "map-placeholder")!)
        completionHandler(image)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to apply the same principle to WKWebViews, but how can you take a screenshot of the WKWebView when the view is not open on the device. Unfortunately, you cannot use WKWebViews in widgets, so there's no way to get the WkWebView on the widget screen, take a screenshot, then display the screenshot. Other apps on the App Store seem to have figured this out, so what am I missing?

Comment: Did you find out something? Would be curious how other apps in the store did it.

Comment: never figured it out? can't have it offscreen?